# The Worst Part about Coding

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle, haiku

> Torture I do you
>   I am better than brainf***
>   I love *String Theory*

What am I?

Hint:

> *String Theory* is italicized for a reason. Figure it out!

Comment: who the hell named their coding brainf***?

Comment: Is String Theory actual String Theory in Physics or is it a play on words for a concatenated character data type in programming (a.k.a: a 'String').

Comment: @Daedric There are 19 movies / TV series / episodes titled "String Theory" in IMDb, it might be one of those. Unfortunately, none is particularly popular.

Comment: Also, I think there's an error in the puzzle: nothing is better than brainf*** ;)

Comment: @feelinferrety: Not sure if the"Worse" instead of "Worst" in the original title was a hint, perhaps?

Comment: @KeyboardWielder I don't *think* so, given this user's history and language usage, but they are welcome to roll back if so.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That post!  THAT POST!!! \**spends all day looking at it\**

Comment: @feelinferrety Lol, just that post? Then I won't suggest looking at the other posts on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes. ;p

Comment: I never expected that this question would be so popular! Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you be:

> regular expressions

Explanation:

> A regular expression is used to find a complex search pattern in a string.  Its syntax uses a whole bunch of special characters including:
>  `. * ? + [ ] ( ) { } < > ^ $`
>  ... which can make it difficult to read and debug

Comment: This is a good answer, might even be the winning one. Do you mind adding some explanations for those who don't know how it satisfies the hints?

Comment: @Reti43: Added some explanation.  But I have my doubts about this being the right answer.

Comment: You did it. YAY!!

Comment: You did it or He did it...

Answer (score 2):

My answer:

> [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Torture I do you

> Sounds like something Yoda would say. And it's torturing to do the Yoda conditions.

I am better than brainf***

> Everything is better than [Brainf**k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

I love String Theory

> The Yoda Condition means putting the constant part of an evaluation in front of the variable. `"a" == b`  So it may mean string before variable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> Comments

Since :

> they are strings and every coder hates to comment his/her code.

Comment: Please consider using spoilers in your answer using >! from next time. :)

Comment: Hey... I don't hate it. And I actually do it.

Comment: @manshu you're right but I tried and it didnt work, I've put >! before the line

Comment: @RimaHajou Did you also include a space? So `>! Some text` and not `>!Some text`?

Comment: I saw the edit history. It was because you had not left a line between [your answer] and  'Since'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

> Escaping quotes in strings

Because

> It's annoying to escape the quotes used sometimes (although I don't find it torture personally).
>  For example: `"a \"string\""` OR `'a \'string\''`
>
>  Not sure about the [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) part though. Since Brainfuck doesn't use single nor double quotes to print text.. (as shown by the `Hello World!` example on the wiki page)

Answer (score 0):

You must be:

> machine code

Because:

> nothing can be tougher than coding in 1 and 0 in pure machine code :D

Answer (score 0):

Another answer:

> Lisp

Explanation:

> Lisp is a programming language that uses Polish prefix notation and a lots of parentheses.
>  Also, in *The Big Bang Theory*, string theorist Barry Kripke has a speech impediment similar to a lisp.